# Rails/SimpleForm: How do I specify the params for two sets of nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, simple-form-for

I have a model that has two different associations with another model:

```rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer, required: true
  belongs_to :delivery_address,
             class_name: 'Address',
             foreign_key: :delivery_address_id
  belongs_to :collection_address,
             class_name: 'Address',
             foreign_key: :collection_address_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collection_address, :delivery_address
end
```

It accepts nested attributes:

```rb
<h1>Edit order</h1>
<%= simple_form_for @order, url: order_path do |form| %>
    <strong>Collection address</strong>
    <%= form.simple_fields_for @collection_address, as: :collection_address do |collection_address_form| %>
      <%= collection_address_form.input :address1 %>
        ...
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <strong>Re-delivery address</strong>
    <%= form.simple_fields_for @redelivery_address, as: :delivery_address do |delivery_address_form| %>
      <%= delivery_address_form.input :address1 %>
      ...
    <% end %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I want to receive two sets of params: `params[:collection_address` and `params[:delivery_address`.

However when the form submits, the controller does not receive params for both addresses. Instead it receives one set under the key `params[:address]`.

I understand that `form_for` accepts the `:as` option. I've used it above. I expect to gete `params[:delivery_address]` and `params[:collection_address]` but I only get `params[:address]`.

Is this supposed to work with Simple Form or do I need to do something different? Is there anything wrong with my code that's preventing the two sets of params from being created?

Comment: I think it has something to do with `:address1` being used for both.

Comment: You really should not need to pass a instance variable to `simple_fields_for`. Just pass the name of the association. `form.simple_fields_for :collection_address`. Also `url: order_path` is superfluous. Convention over configuration baby!

Comment: I specified `order_path` because the controller differs to the model. I have reasons. But yes, would have preferred convention over configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the

`<%= delivery_address_form.input :address1, input_html: {name:'delivery_address[address1]' } %>`

for each of the fields. I know this feels kind of dirty, but eh... It's going to get the job done